# Delete duplicates on excel drop down list without creating a new table

Tags: excel, list, duplicates, dropdown

Let's say I have two sheets; **Sheet1** and **Sheet2**.

On **Sheet1**, I put *"Transactions"* on column A and *"Currency"* on column B. Each transaction has one currency (EUR, AUD, or USD, etc.) and this is already a dropdown list references a "Currency" table on another sheet.

On **Sheet2**, I need to write a report on the transactions and I need to have a dropdown list on column D with all the currencies from **Sheet1**. I tried the Data Validation

=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2;0;0;1000;1)

but the new dropdown list on **Sheet2** was shown with duplicates (e.g. EUR; EUR; EUR; AUD; AUD; USD) and I want to just have e.g.EUR; AUD; USD.

I tried looking for answers but all of them suggest to create a new table with just the currencies from **Sheet1** without the duplicates. I need an answer where I don't have to create that, just by changing the formula for the Data Validation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please show some screenshots of your current data, and what your "expected" outcome should look like (i.e sheet 2 with fake values added)

Comment: @Badja I'm still figuring out how to add pics/screenshot on SO, so I'm going to explain it instead :)
 In the dropdown list of Currency on Sheet2, I want to have EUR-AUD-USD, but instead the dropdown list shows EUR-EUR-EUR-AUD-AUD-USD because on Sheet1 I have 3 transactions with EUR, 2 with AUD, and 1 with USD. I hope it's not confusing :)

Comment: To add pictures, you can take a screenshot (Shift + Win + S), then paste into your question with Ctrl + V. I'll add as an answer what I think you can do though

Comment: Hello there. I don't think Excel can do it the way you want. You can extract unique elements from a range but you need an auxiliary table and array formulas. In google sheets you can easily do this with dynamic arrays (something that is coming to MS Excel soon) using the UNIQUE formula.

Comment: @Lucas thank you. I need exactly that, something like select distinct on SQL, but it's good to know that it's not there in MS Excel (yet).